# How to show a corresponding element from child Component at onClick event in main Component in React?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm building my first React project. I have a list that drops down on-hover on my main homepage, inside the drop-down, I'm trying to show specific list details with my child Component. I got the click-to-show function to work, but can't seem to make it work with showing the right corresponding detail (black&white parent should show black&white text description). My current code below:

```
class Style extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { showDetail: false };
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick() {
    this.setState((state) => ({
      showDetail: !state.showDetail,
    }));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <section className="style">
        <div className="style-list">
          <p onClick={this.handleClick}>
            Black & White</p>
          <p onClick={this.handleClick}>
            Modern</p>
          <p onClick={this.handleClick}>
            Old School</p>
        </div>
        <div className="style-description">
          {this.state.showDetail ? <StyleDetail /> : null}
        </div>
      </section>

class StyleDetail extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p id="blackwhite">black&white description text</p>
        <p id="modern">modern description text</p>
        <p id="oldschool">oldschool description text</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Do I need key values to make this work? Or do I need to declare my corresponding elements as variables? Can't seem to wrap my head around it. Thanks in advance for any help!

From a newbie developer xx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new state to store current style and pass it to the `StyleDetail` component.

```
import React from "react";

class Style extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      showDetail: false,
      currentStyle: ""
    };
    this.changeStyle= this.changeStyle.bind(this);
  }

  changeStyle(clickedStyle) {
    let newState = {
      currentStyle: clickedStyle
    };
    if (clickedStyle === this.state.currentStyle) {
      newState.showDetail = !this.state.showDetail;
    }
    this.setState(newState);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <section className="style">
        <div className="style-list">
          <p onClick={e => this.changeStyle("B&W")}>Black & White</p>
          <p onClick={e => this.changeStyle("modern")}>Modern</p>
          <p onClick={e => this.changeStyle("old-school")}>Old School</p>
        </div>
        <div className="style-description">
          {this.state.showDetail && (
            <StyleDetail currentStyle={this.state.currentStyle} />
          )}
        </div>
      </section>
    );
  }
}

export default Style;


import React from "react";

class StyleDetail extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.currentStyle === "B&W" && (
          <p id="blackwhite">black&white description text</p>
        )}
        {this.props.currentStyle === "modern" && (
          <p id="modern">modern description text</p>
        )}
        {this.props.currentStyle === "old-school" && (
          <p id="oldschool">oldschool description text</p>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default StyleDetail;
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thank you so much! This makes sense. Although why do I get the error of
" TypeError: Cannot read property 'dataset' of null " when I try in my code?

Comment: @JessieYingyingGong It seems it was caused by `Event Pooling`. You can read about it [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#event-pooling). I've updated the answer. Did it fix the error?

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH! It works! I'm exporting child Component as const variable now, since it's only doing the render function. I also added another hover component, and it all works! Really cool to get the logic of it. Thank you!

Comment: Happy to help :)